# Callback после выполнения цикла

Tags: node.js

Никак не могу понять эту асинхронность, непонятно как решить проблему:

```
function get1(other_color_href, callback) {
    var arr_temp = [];
    other_color_href.forEach(function (item) {
        getOtherAdditional(item, function (err, arr) {
            arr_temp.push(arr);
        });
    });
    callback(false,arr_temp); // это надо выполнить после работы цикла, а то получается, что происходит кэллбэк сначала, а потом выполняется сам цикл
}
```

Большая просьба не тыкать носом в сторону aSync, хочу так понять сначала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендую библиотеку async. Там есть метод [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each). Делает то, что вам надо.

Про не тыкать носом в async не прочитал сначала))) Почему так происходит.

```
function get1(other_color_href, callback) {
var arr_temp = [];
other_color_href.forEach(function (item) {
    getOtherAdditional(item, function (err, arr) {
        arr_temp.push(arr);
    });
    /*Если ф-я getOtherAdditional асинхронная, то код не будет дожидаться ее выполнения и попрет исполнятся дальше выполнять следующую итерацию. Когда он (код) закончит forEach он выполнит строку callback(false,arr_temp);. И, смею вас уверить, на момент выполнения коллбэка ни одна ф-я getOtherAdditional не будет выполнена. За подробностями http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast (видео 20-22)  */
});
callback(false,arr_temp);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Логично, что тебе нужно дождаться выполнения всех коллбеков внутри `forEach` :)

Пример:

```
function get1(other_color_href, callback) {
    var arr_temp = [];
    // счетчик итераций
    var count_success = other_color_href.length;

    other_color_href.forEach(function (item) {
        getOtherAdditional(item, function (err, arr) {
            count_success--;
            arr_temp.push(arr);

            if(count_success == 0) {
                callback(false,arr_temp); 
            }
        });
    });
}
```